# Проблема с Ajax при переходе с вкладки на вкладку

Tags: javascript, ajax

Почему после перехода на другую вкладку браузера, и после возвращения на вкладку с проектом вызывается новый Ajax запрос(или даже несколько)?

```
'use strict'

// Weather obj
var weather = {
  id: 0,
  geo_options: {
    timeout: 2000
  },
  geo_error: () => {
      console.log("sorry, it's error");
  },
  showWeather: function() {
       var target = {
         latitude: 0,
         longitude: 0
      };
       var getPosition = (position) => {
        var link = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='
        + position.coords.latitude + '&lon=' + position.coords.longitude
        +'&units=metric&lang=ru&appid=b231606340553d9174136f7f083904b3';
        this.getRequest(link);
       }
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.id)
          return this.id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(getPosition, weather.geo_error(), weather.geo_options);

  },
  getRequest: function(link) {
    var $this = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', link , true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if(this.status == 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          $this.showWeatherData(response);
          }
        }
      }
  },
  showWeatherData: function(response) {
    showIcon(response);
    temperature.innerHTML = response.main.temp + " &deg;C";
    humidity.innerHTML = response.main.humidity;
    description.innerHTML = response.weather[0].description;
  },
  showCityWeather: function() {
     var getPosition = () => {
      var cityName = choiseCityName.value;
      var link = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&units=metric&lang=ru&appid=b231606340553d9174136f7f083904b3';
      return this.getRequest(link);
  }
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.id)
    return this.id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(getPosition, weather.geo_error(), weather.geo_options);
  }
};
// Functions
  function showIcon(response) {
    var id = response.weather[0];
    for (var key in id) {
      if (key == "id") {
          id = id[key];
          var codes = {
            P: [200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 232], //Thunderlight
            Q: [300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321], //Dizzle
            R: [500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 511, 520, 521, 522, 531], //Rain
            W: [600, 601, 602, 611, 612, 615, 616, 620, 621, 622], // Snow
            M: [701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 762, 771, 781], // Fog
            B: [800], // Clear
            H: [801], // Few clouds
            N: [802], // Scattered clouds
            Y: [803, 804] // Broken clouds
            };
      var data = ')'; // If n/a
      for (var symbol in codes) {
        if (codes[symbol].indexOf(id) >= 0) {
          data = symbol;
        }
      }
      return icon.setAttribute("data-icon", data);
      }
    }
  };

   weather.showWeather();

   getCity.addEventListener('click', function() {
     return weather.showCityWeather();
   });
   myGeoWeather.addEventListener('click', function() {
     return weather.showWeather();
   })


   choiseCityName.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("Вы нажали Enter!");
    }
    // Отменяем действие браузера
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Что за элементы `getCity` и `myGeoWeather`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko это buttons

Comment: Приведите пример `html` кода.Также, возможно при активации вкладки срабатывает событие `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, https://github.com/pibodi/myWeather/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` выполняется каждый раз при активации вкладки.

Посмотрите пример:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/f9ax6vw2/)

```js
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
  console.log('position', position);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('error', error);
}, {
  timeout: 2000
})
```

P.S. Пример смотрите на `jsfiddle`, предварительно разрешите в браузере геолокацию. Сниппет не работает.

Если вам не нужно постоянно отслеживать местоположение, можете воспользоваться функцией `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

Посмотрите пример:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/z8fchmxr/)

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  console.log('position', position);
}, (error) => {
  console.log('error', error);
})
```

Comment: Это специфика его работы?

Comment: Так, с этим я все понял. Спасибо большое. Но я не понял почему при первом запуске скрипта запрос 2 или даже три раза делается (удачный с кодом 200)

Comment: @АртемАндреев С использованием `getCurrentPosition` 2 или 3 раза запрос делается?

Comment: При `watchPosition`

Comment: @АртемАндреев Я вам даже больше скажу - он иногда вызывается при просто просмотре сайта, не при первом запуске. Видимо, он считает, что позиция меняется.

Comment: То есть если  метод объекта `weather` был вызван один раз с `watchPosition`, то он уже своей жизнью живет?

Comment: @АртемАндреев Ну, как бы название функции `watchPosition` намекает, что он будет следить за изменением `position`. И при каждом изменении (или других событиях, которые определяет браузер) будет запускать ваш `callback`.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо большое. Я вообще убрал `watchPosition` из проекта

Comment: А можете оценить код и указать на недочёты? Просто только учусь)

Comment: @АртемАндреев Оценить могу. Но не бесплатно. Если интересно, мои контакты есть в профиле.